# Listing all users in mysql root DB

Tags: mysql

In mysql CLI I did `show databases;` I then got a list of all DBs.

How could I list all users? `show users;` didn't work, and I didn't find a command [here](https://gist.github.com/hofmannsven/9164408) in a quick search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `mysql` prompt list only users

```
mysql> SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
```

list users and hosts

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely you're looking for...

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf -e "SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;"
```

You system may use ~/.my.cnf or you may require passing -u + -p.